# how to create an object from a python array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following structure, which I convert from a .txt with pandas

```
 [[000001, 'PEPE                  ', 'S', 'LAST_NAME   ', 'CIP  ', 'CELLPHONE'],
 [0000002, 'LUIS  ', 'S', 'ADRESS  ', '                       ', 'nan'],
 [0000003, 'PEDRO               ', 'S', 'STREET ', 'CITY', ' nan']]
```

My code

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\PRUEBA.txt'

columns = ("service", "name", "Active", "reference1", "reference2", "reference3")
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="|", names=columns, header=None)
cl = df.values.tolist()
print(cl)
```

but to be able to give it the treatment, which it requires, either by removing the empty strings and nan, how can I transform the service to int and create an object based on the service and the references in this way.

```
[
  { service: 1, name: 'PEPE', order: 0, ref: 'LAST_NAME' },
  { service: 1, name: 'PEPE', order: 1, ref: 'CIP' },
  { service: 1, name: 'PEPE', order: 2, ref: 'CELLPHONE' },
  { service: 2, name: 'LUIS', order: 0, ref: 'ADRESS' },
  { service: 3, name: 'PEDRO', order: 0, ref: 'STREET' },
  { service: 3, name: 'PEDRO', order: 1, ref: 'CITY' }
]
```

How can I achieve this, very grateful for your comments

Comment: `d.to_dict('records')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key: Use [df.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to unpivot the table and subsequently perform [df.to_dict(orient='records')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to convert the dataframe to a record-oriented `dict` as mentioned by @QuangHoang. The rest are regular filtering and miscellaneous adjustments.

```
# data
ls = [['000001', 'PEPE                  ', 'S', 'LAST_NAME   ', 'CIP  ', 'CELLPHONE'],
      ['0000002', 'LUIS  ', 'S', 'ADRESS  ', '                       ', 'nan'],
      ['0000003', 'PEDRO               ', 'S', 'STREET ', 'CITY', ' nan']
      ]
df = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=("service", "name", "Active", "reference1", "reference2", "reference3"))

# reformat and strip over each column
for col in df:
    if col == "service":
        df[col] = df[col].astype(int)
    else:
        df[col] = df[col].str.strip()  # accessor

# unpivot and adjust
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=["service", "name"],
              value_vars=["reference1", "reference2", "reference3"],
              value_name="ref")\
    .sort_values(by="service")\
    .drop("variable", axis=1)\
    .reset_index(drop=True)

# filter out empty or nan
df2 = df2[~df2["ref"].isin(["", "nan"])]

# generate order numbering by group
df2["order"] = df2.groupby("service").cumcount()
df2 = df2[["service", "name", "order", "ref"]]  # reorder

# convert to a record-oriented dict
df2.to_dict(orient='records')

Out[99]: 
[{'service': 1, 'name': 'PEPE', 'order': 0, 'ref': 'LAST_NAME'},
 {'service': 1, 'name': 'PEPE', 'order': 1, 'ref': 'CIP'},
 {'service': 1, 'name': 'PEPE', 'order': 2, 'ref': 'CELLPHONE'},
 {'service': 2, 'name': 'LUIS', 'order': 0, 'ref': 'ADRESS'},
 {'service': 3, 'name': 'PEDRO', 'order': 0, 'ref': 'STREET'},
 {'service': 3, 'name': 'PEDRO', 'order': 1, 'ref': 'CITY'}]
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot <3, but how do I put the read_csv in your solution? and excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Is the format of your `df` different from mine? (you can check by `df.dtypes`)

Comment: Yes, service = int32, how could I increase it by reading int64 and how would you do the same, what did you do above, but the .txt with df.read_csv? dtypes: int32 service
name object
int64 order
object ref

Comment: I don't think my code will break because of the difference between using np.int32 and np.int64. Just perform `df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int32)` if you don't need int64, or vice versa.

Comment: The last question returns me invalid literal for int () with bae 10: '\ x1a' and if I print the data types, all in the line before the for all are objects type

Comment: I cannot test what I don't have. And IMHO you should not expect an answerer to do this for you. The file format must be broken, but I cannot say anything about a file which I don't have.

Comment: my apologies, it is the same format, only that before the "for", they are all objects type and there, if it bursts the error appears I have tried to convert the column "service" to int before the for, but still it gives me an error, I continue reviewing and thanks for your comments hehehe